# Exporting Googlechart to PDF but getting content as table or list

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a html code which is supposed to generate pdf of a div on click of button Content in the chart is Googlechart  but getting content as table or list.
PDF is getting generated.But No chart is there.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://parall.ax/parallax/js/jspdf.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript">
    google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
    function drawChart() {
      var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ["Element", "Density", { role: "style" } ],
        ["Copper", 8.94, "#b87333"],
        ["Silver", 10.49, "silver"],
        ["Gold", 19.30, "gold"],
        ["Platinum", 21.45, "color: #e5e4e2"]
      ]);

      var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
      view.setColumns([0, 1,
                       { calc: "stringify",
                         sourceColumn: 1,
                         type: "string",
                         role: "annotation" },
                       2]);

      var options = {
        bar: {groupWidth: "95%"},
        legend: { position: "none" },
      };
      var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById("barchart_values"));
      chart.draw(view, options);
  }



  </script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/0.9.0rc1/jspdf.min.js"></script>
 <script  language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
    var doc = new jsPDF();
    var specialElementHandlers = {'#editor': function (element, renderer) {
        return true;
        }
    };

    $('#cmd').click(function () {
        alert("hi");

        doc.fromHTML($('#barchart_values').html(), 15, 15, {
                        'width': 170,
                        'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
        });
        doc.save('sample-file.pdf');
    });
    }); 
    </script>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="barchart_values" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;border:1px solid red;"></div>

<div id="editor"></div>
<button id="cmd">generate PDF</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: where is your element with `id` `barchart_values`? I think that is the issue.

Comment: try replacing this in your code: `doc.fromHTML($('#content').html(), 15, 15, {`. See if that is working. I believe you want to convert div with `id` `content` into a PDF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you got a racing condition somehow, your document is not ready when you trying to retriving the value,

do this:

```
 $('#cmd').click(function () {
    alert("hi");
      setTimeout(function(){  

       if($('#barchart_values').length){
    doc.fromHTML($('#barchart_values').html(), 15, 15, {
                    'width': 170,
                    'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
    });
    doc.save('sample-file.pdf');
  }
  else{alert('no barchar value')}

 }, 500);
});
```

Also, make sure your #barchart_values exist and have the values it expects

A full example of converting google chart to pdf using jspdf,
http://www.tothenew.com/blog/generate-pdf-for-google-charts-through-javascript/

Comment: `click` event is being attached inside `$(document).ready`. How the race condition will occur ?

Comment: I has't see the #barchart_values element, if it's been injected dynamictly, then that's the issue

Comment: @user3133364, show me your #barchart_values element

Comment: @user3133364, i've updated my code, try again, see what happens

Comment: Got it Now content is coming.But what i have is a googlechat and the content which is getting exported as pdf  is table

Comment: @user3133364, Ok, so exporting is working now, and now only the content is incorrect?

Comment: @vijayP, undo down vote for my answer bro, he got it solved from my code , lol

Comment: Yeah content is different

Comment: @KevinSimple - still I am not getting where is `$('#barchart_values')`. Do you really feel above code works if there is zero element with id `barchart_values`? I think user has posted wrong HTML.

Comment: @user3133364, #barchart_values is the element, make sure it has the correct content, if you can show me your google chart htmel content, then it's easy to solve

Comment: @user3133364, I got your issue, you can not use jspdf.js to convert google chart to pdf straight forward unfortunately, jspdf.js is for pure html,images, but your chart is rendered using google chart lib, you need convert your chart to png image first, then use jspdf to convert to pdf, I got a sample for you, look at my updated answer, also, please tick my answer bro, lol, happy coding

Comment: @vijayP, the html was only partial, but it seems my guess was right, he got a racing condition when rendering chart, up vote my answer bro , lol , happy coding!

Comment: @KevinSimple - ok I m up voting it. But please try to understand me. I believe we are here to help each other. Initially user posted the HTML without `barchart_values`. So user's code OR your code will not work even if you put 50 seconds setTimeout delay. So as soon as you have seen the user's code you should have asked where is the `barchart_values`. You can see my comment to question. Before your answer I asked the same question to user almost 3 min before your answer. If the user has posted correct HTML he would have got the answer more earlier. Also code never works on assumption... `:)`!

Comment: @vijayP, yes, you are right mate, I didn't see the barchart_values as well, I was just guessing, as race condition is quite common to cause this issue, lol, I completely understand you mate, :)

Comment: Thanks @KevinSimple...nice talking with you..`:)`!